# Iterating and Mapping Dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have two Dataframes
First DataFrame Consists of columns: name, product, ACC

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['rabbit', 'dog', 'squirrel', 'cat', 'donkey', 'missing',],
    'product': ['carrot', 'bone', 'carrot', 'milk', 'missing', 'meat',],
    'Acc':['low','Medium','High','low','medium','High']
})
```

[image: df1]

Second DataFrame: ID, name_product,type,source,target

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,],
    'name_product': ['milk', 'bone', 'carrot', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'donkey', 'donkey', 'squirrel',],
    'type': ['attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute', 'attribute',],
    'source': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
    'target': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
})
```

[image: df2]

The source, destination, are mapped and fed using IDs of the second data frame after identifying the pattern of the first data frame.
The Property column is to be fed by using the pattern(name, product) of the first DataFrame.

The below code is used to identify the patterns and used to create a third data frame for mapping purposes but was unable to map the properties.

```
feed = dict()
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['product'] in feed.keys():
          feed[row['product']].append(row['name'])
    else:
          feed[row['product']] = [row['name']]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'name_product', 'type', 'source', 'target','Property'])
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row['name_product'] in feed.keys():
          animals = feed[row['name_product']]
          animal_id_list = df2[df2['name_product'].isin(animals)]['id'].to_list()
          for animal_id in animal_id_list:
              df3 = df3.append({'id': f"{row['id']},{animal_id}", 'type': 'transition', 'source': row['id'], 'target': animal_id}, ignore_index=True)
else:
    pass
```

My Third Dataframe looks like this[image: my_df3]

My expected Third DataFrame: [image]

Answer (score 1):

You aren't mapping the column "Property" because... you aren't mapping the column "Property" when you add rows to df3.  The following code results in what you want:

```
feed = dict()
acc = dict()
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    acc[row['name']] = row['Acc']
    if row['product'] in feed.keys():
          feed[row['product']].append(row['name'])
    else:
          feed[row['product']] = [row['name']]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'name_product', 'type', 'source', 'target','Property'])
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row['name_product'] in feed.keys():
          animals = feed[row['name_product']]
          for animal in animals:
              animal_id_list = df2[df2['name_product'].isin([animal])]['id'].to_list()
              for animal_id in animal_id_list:
                  df3 = df3.append({'id': f"{row['id']},{animal_id}", 'type': 'transition', 'source': row['id'], 'target': animal_id, 'Property':acc[animal]}, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        pass
```

Note that this was just solving the issue as fast as possible by creating a new mapping from the animal name to the "Acc" property from df1.  There is undoubtedly a better way to solve this problem by merging df1 and df2.  I would also recommend using a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) for your source/target pairs.